# How can I solve "faill deployment of vercel"?

Tags: deployment, vercel

in my vercel log

$ run-s build:css react-scripts:build

19:44:19.549ERROR: Task not found: "react-scripts:build"

19:44:19.561error Command failed with exit code 1.

19:44:19.561info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

19:44:19.579Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with

119:44:20.152BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1

```
//package.json

"scripts": {
"build:css": "postcss src/styles/tailwind.css -o src/styles/app.css",
"watch:css": "postcss src/styles/tailwind.css -o src/styles/app.css --watch",
"react-scripts:start": "react-scripts start",
"start": "run-p watch:css react-scripts:start",
"build": "run-s build:css react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
```

I need help from this...
I spent more than 4 hours to fix it...
but still working on it.